# How to ignore protected readonly member of class during serialization

Tags: json, typescript, class, encapsulation, protected

Suppose I have a class in Typescript with a protected readonly member that's a constructor argument, and multiple classes that extend from the class and use that property:

```
class Yolo {
    public readonly swolo: boolean = false;
    // Lots of other properties

    constructor(protected readonly swag: string = '') {}
}
```

and I want the string that results from `JSON.stringify(new Yolo())` to not have any `swag`:

```
{"swolo":false, ...(Every other property except "swag")}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this *by exclusion* (i.e., not using a second parameter on `JSON.stringify`) because there are many other properties on the class, *and still retain Intellisense*?

My initial inclination was to write `toJSON` as something like

```
public toJSON() {
    const serializableEntries: {
        -readonly [K in keyof Yolo]: Yolo[K]
    } = {
        ...this
    };

    delete serializableEntries.swag;
    return serializableEntries;
}
```

but that results in a compilation error because `keyof Yolo` doesn't include `swag`:

> Property 'swag' does not exist on type '{ toJSON: () => string; }'.

I've considered the following workarounds:

1. I could cast to `any` in `toJSON`
2. I could remove the `readonly`
   modifier from the Class declaration and remove the type declaration on `serializableEntries` in `toJSON`
3. I could make `swag` public

but none of those options are favorable in my opinion. I would like to keep Intellisense and the access modifiers as-is. Is it even possible?

Comment: use getters if you can.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that in the description but that's not possible because the property is actually dynamic. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
public toJSON(): string {
    const { swag: _, ...props } = this;
    return JSON.stringify(props);
}
```

That has the effect of copying all properties of `this` into `props` except for the `swag` property.

```
console.log(new Yolo("shwag").toJSON()); //{"swolo":false}
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECaD2J7QN4ChqegBwK4CMQBLYaAJwFMwATeAOxAE9oIB3ReALmn3kSrrQAvNABmYEBAoBuDFgD086ABl4AFxjxR0dQAsKZHGXjYDaohQho5mYPQhqyuYGvhkAFNmNqKLitXIqWgZmNjAAc24HMiI6cOFoAHJEgEpUaABfGxwCYlJXACkAZQB5ADl3FKjHWPj0LAboOzoHdLDI6AB9ABpoADoBrxMYDIS1XSIIWUasSjVcMkFi8r7o2qJRRk9jbAgU6awsrLRmiH4+pHD3OgpWOA53ACIIXVYIx5S+wtKKlP3oRQoZ7sJCPTjiSQUDJAA)

Comment: Love it, thanks. I always forget about this feature because the syntax jukes the hell outta me.